drawArc() `s working in DrawScope in jetpack compose?
Actually i am  reading this article . I am so confuse about the working of startAngle , and direction of arc in drawArc() , can  anyone explain this ?
I have read many answers in jetpack compose .  i have wasted about 2 to 3 hours  to try to understand this function .
In below code why half circle is on left side . as both angles are positive so it should be on right side ?
Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun PreviewAnimatedRectComposable() {
   GooglePhotosIcon()
}




@Composable
private fun GooglePhotosIcon() {
   Canvas(
       modifier = Modifier
           .size(100.dp)
           .padding(16.dp)
           .border(1.dp , Color.Magenta)
   ) {
       drawArc(
           color = Color(0xFFf04231),
           startAngle = 270f,
           sweepAngle = 180f,
           useCenter = true,
           size = Size(size.width * .50f, size.height * .50f),
           topLeft = Offset(size.width * .25f, 0f)
       )
   }
}


Actually i get diagram random from google image

So in android y axis is opposite that of the cristian coordinate system .
so StartAngle : indicate starting position of arc
sweepAngle : indicate extent of arc
If any those angle is negative then direction of arc is anticlockwise otherwise clockwise .
From startAngle we decide where arc go either clockwise or anticlockwise depending upon either startAngle or sweepAngle is positive or negative .
So in my code start angle is on top of circle and so all angle are positive so it draw arc in clockwise direction .
